# Issue in Writing MATLAB Recursive Function

Tags: matlab, recursion

Having a bit of difficulty writing up a recursive function...for some reason, it's not taking the input.

```
function [FinalAinput, FinalMaxError] = recursiveExcelWenie(P, A, Ainput, D)
    Aoutput = ExcelWenie_fn(P, A, D)
    [MaxError, Ainput] = ExcelWenie2_fn(Aoutput, A)
    if MaxError < 1
         FinalAinput = Ainput
         FinalMaxError = MaxError
    else
         NewInput = Ainput
         [Final] = recursiveExcelWenie(P, A, NewInput, D)
    end
end
```

I'm trying to have the recursiveExcelWenie function take the Ainput vector generated by ExcelWenie2_fn and run itself again with this new input. The error should be whittling down significantly as I go through each step until the maximum error across all error values from the MaxError vector is less than 1, but it just endlessly loops. Where did I go wrong, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where do you assign your return variables, `FinalAinput` and `FinalMaxError`?

Comment: @beaker I changed my code to reflect this issue. Definitely saved me trouble along the line, but the current change didn't solve the problem at hand. Did I do something wrong, or am I still missing the bigger picture?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you posted. Have you tried looking at `MaxError` in the debugger?

Comment: @Beaker Yes, it's the same value whenever I print it out. What's odd is that the output generated from recursiveExcelWenie doesn't change when I feed it new input.

Comment: So maybe it's not getting updated properly in `ExcelWenie2_fn`...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to use `[FinalAinput, FinalMaxError]` as the return values from your recursive call. That's the only way the results will get passed back up the stack.

Comment: @beaker Just in case, I'm going to go over ExcelWenie2_fn. Maybe I messed something up there.

Comment: @beaker I actually found a few issues in my prior codes that necessitated me to add a counter in to count for some base case issues I hadn't looked at first. Nevertheless, I've got it figured out. Thanks so much for making me think about the bug in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your function like this:

```
function [FinalAinput, FinalMaxError] = recursiveExcelWenie(P, A, Ainput, D)
    Aoutput = ExcelWenie_fn(P, A, D)
    [MaxError, Ainput] = ExcelWenie2_fn(Aoutput, A)
    if MaxError < 1
         FinalAinput = Ainput
         FinalMaxError = MaxError
    else
         NewInput = Ainput
         [FinalAinput, FinalMaxError]= recursiveExcelWenie(P, A, NewInput, D)
    end
end
```